# Error: Automation server can't create object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activexobject

I have this line of code, which throws an error in **IE-11** browser,

```
var excApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
```

The following error occurs:
**Error: Automation server can't create object.**

is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ActiveXObject in IE11:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> Starting with IE11, the navigator object supports plugins and
>   mimeTypes properties. In addition, the window.ActiveXObject property
>   is hidden from the DOM. (This means you can no longer use the property
>   to detect IE11.)

Comment: ActiveXObjects are indeed supported in IE11. See the "Note" underneath the JavaScript example in the link that you posted.
"IE11 still supports the ActiveXObject object type and you can use it to instantiate ActiveX controls. It is, however, no longer supported as a property of the window object."